# Guidance on how to set a plane to look like the sea during a storm

Tags: texturing

I am a complete Blender beginner and I am trying to follow this beginner's course as suggested by this forum:

http://www.cdschools.org/cms/lib04/PA09000075/Centricity/Domain/81/BlenderBasics_4thEdition2011.pdf

However, I am stuck cause I cannot get the right texture for the water DESPITE doing everything exactly like the instructor says.

In the link below you're see a screenshot of my 2 monitors displaying:

Left Monitor: My Blender 3d with 2 windows, left most showing the rendered texture for the water

Right Monitor: The instructor's PDF file showing how the water should display.

Link is here--> http://snag.gy/eFMIi.jpg

Can someone help me out with this please?

Answer (score 2):

[image]Turn off colour in the influence panel. Only apply this to the normal map

Comment: Hi, I tried that but the result is the same  - could it be because I use the blender renders (not the cycles one?): http://snag.gy/n3tea.jpg

Comment: Hmmm it could be something to do with the physics tab properties